# Java Sprite Animation - Can't seem to get my sprite to redraw Properly

Tags: java, swing, animation, canvas, sprite

I've been attempting some sprite animation in with Java and redrawing it, however I can't seem to get my sprite to redraw properly on the Canvas. At first the Problem was that the Previous frames were still there in the back ground of the Canvas when I re-drew it so in order to fix that I added a call to .clearRect(); However while adding the call to that function did fix that problem it caused me to start loosing frames like crazy. I've searched and tried a few things but could find a solution and as near as I can figure .clearRect() is on occasion getting executed after .drawImage(). the Code for my canvas is as Fallows:

```
package rpg;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Sprite extends Canvas{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private BufferedImage img;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Sprite(int width, int height, BufferedImage img){
        this.img = img;
        setSize(width, height);
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);

     }

    public void changeSprite(BufferedImage img)
    {
        this.img = img;
        repaint();

    }





}
```

Note: I'm Working with a Transparent background and would like to keep it transparent.

Comment: The only reason to use Canvas is to take advantage of the BufferStrategy

Answer (score 1):

> At first the Problem was that the Previous frames were still there in the back ground of the Canvas when I re-drew it so in order to fix that I added a call to .clearRect();

Don't use clearRect(). Instead you should use `fillRect(...)` to paint the background color of the component.

The following is from the API of the clearRect() method:

*Beginning with Java 1.1, the background color of offscreen images may be system dependent. Applications should use setColor followed by fillRect to ensure that an offscreen image is cleared to a specific color.*

However, you don't even need to do that. When you override a painting method you need to invoke super.thePaintingMethod(...). In this case you are attempting to override the paint() method so the first statement should be:

```
super.paint(g);
```

Then the default painting code of the component will paint the background for you.

Also, this is not Swing painting code. This is AWT code. You really should tag your question properly. We don't know if you are actually trying to do painting using Swing techniques or whether you found old AWT painting code and assume it is the same in Swing.

> I'm working with a transparent background

Umm... And why are you trying to use AWT? You still haven't qualified your question. Since you haven't removed the "Swing" tag, I assume you are using Swing.

Using Swing the code would be:

```
JLabel sprite = new JLabel( new ImageIon(...) );
```

That's it. One line of code. No need for a custom class.

To change the image you would then just use:

```
sprite.setIcon( new ImageIcon(...) );
```

Comment: Umm.... I'm working with a transparent background and I would like to keep it transparent.

Comment: Also, I tried calling the super.paint(g); method instead but It Just did the same as the .clearRect();

Answer (score 0):

Probably this little example code helps you...

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

class Player {
     public float health;
     public float yvel;
     public float xvel;
     public float x;
     public float y;
     public BufferedImage image;
     public void work(Graphics g, int[] keys) {
         g.drawImage(image,(int)x,(int)y,null);
         if (keys[0]==1) { //Is the UP-Key pressed
             yvel=yvel-1;
         }
         if (keys[1]==1) { //Is the DOWN-Key pressed
             yvel=yvel+1;
         }
         if (keys[2]==1) { //Is the LEFT-Key pressed
             xvel=xvel-1;
         }
         if (keys[3]==1) { //Is the RIGHT-Key pressed
             xvel=xvel+1;
         }
         x=x+xvel;
         y=y+yvel;
         xvel=xvel-(xvel/4); //One fourth gets lost
         yvel=yvel-(yvel/4); //One fourth gets lost
     }

     public Player(BufferedImage imagew,float xw, float yw, float healthw) {
         x=xw;
         y=yw;
         image=imagew;
         health=healthw;
     }
}
public class Game extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
     public BufferedImage playerimage;
     public Player player;
     public int[] keys=new int[4];

     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                 keys[0]=1;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                 keys[1]=1;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                 keys[2]=1;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                 keys[3]=1;
             }
     }
     public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { 
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                 keys[0]=0;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                 keys[1]=0;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                 keys[2]=0;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                 keys[3]=0;
             }
     }
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                 keys[0]=1;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                 keys[1]=1;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                 keys[2]=1;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                 keys[3]=1;
             }
             if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                 keys[4]=1;
             }
     } 
     public Game(){
          super("Game");
          try {
          playerimage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("player.gif")); //Player Image
          } catch(IOException bug) {
          System.out.println(bug);
          }

          player=new Player(playerimage,100,100,100);

          addKeyListener(this);

          setTitle("Game");

          setContentPane(new Pane());

          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

          setSize(800, 600);

          setResizable(false);

          setVisible(true); 

          long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

          while (true){
              long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
              if (now-start > 40) {
                  System.out.println("FPS : "+Long.toString(1000/(now-start)));
                  start=now;
                  framec++;
                  if (framec==250) {
                      System.gc();
                  }
                  validate();
                  repaint();
              }
          }
     }


     class Pane extends JPanel{
        public Pane() {
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            player.work(g,keys);
        }   
     }
     public static void main(String args[]){
            new Game();
     }
}
```

It draws a controllable player with velocity...
Background should be transparent...